# gsutil rsync CommandException: Destination () must match exactly 1 URL

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a project on cloud storage, a bucket with different directories (one per user) and each directory has different sub directories which are date partitions.

I am using a Jupyter notebook and gsutil.

I downloaded all the files one time from cloud storage to my local machine, using  `!gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket/directory/partition/ destination_directory`.

Now I want to sync any new files added to the directories I already downloaded plus any new directories or partitions that were created since, from the cloud to my local machine.

I tried running
`!gsutil rsync -r 'gs://bucket/user_id**' destination_directory`
and
`!gsutil rsync -r 'gs://bucket/user_id**/**/**.json' destination_directory`

I am using the wildcard to avoid 2 directories that start with a different name.

However I am getting the same error in both cases, and I don't understand why:

> CommandException: Destination (gs://bucket/user_id**) must match exactly 1 URL

Comment: The source wildcards are expanding into multiple source objects. The CLI is interpreting that as multiple destinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gsutil rsync` doesn't support wildcarding of the source or destination URL - only a single URL for each.

That also means there's no way to list the specific objects you want matched the way you're attempting.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized I could solve this by doing rsync -r -x "regex" source destination to exclude the directories I wasn't interested in.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example @RonBorenstein